# replace ALL vowels in a string - RETURN not print

Tags: python, printing, replace, return

How can I want to write a function that takes a string and RETURNS it with every vowel replaced by any number of consecutive copies of itself.

```
def replace(word):
    for c in word:
        if c in 'aeiouAEIOU':
            return word.replace(c, c*5)
```

My code only applies the change to the first vowel then stops, which I assume is because I'm using "return" instead of "print". My assignments, however, are very specific when it comes to creating functions that "return" or "print" - this one says to "return" a new string.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with this question. Atleast OP has tried something.

Comment: Can you provide sample string and expected result

Answer (score 2):

There are two main problems,

1. You are returning immediately, after the first vowel match.
2. Your intention is to change `word` while iterating it.

Since Strings are immutable in Python, you need to create new strings everytime you change something in them. For this particular case, we can use a list comprehension create a new list of characters and then join all of them together finally, to construct a new String like this

```
def replace(word):
    return "".join([c * 5 if c in 'aeiouAEIOU' else c for c in word])

assert replace("a")  == "aaaaa"
assert replace("ab") == "aaaaab"
assert replace("B")  == "B"
```

This program, takes each character from the word with `for c in word` and then checks `if c in 'aeiouAEIOU'`. If that is true, then makes the current element of the list as `c * 5` otherwise leaves the current element as `c` itself. So, before joining, the list would have looked something like this, for the word `Welcome`

```
def replace(word):
    print [c * 5 if c in 'aeiouAEIOU' else c for c in word]
    return "".join([c * 5 if c in 'aeiouAEIOU' else c for c in word])

replace("Welcome")
# ['W', 'eeeee', 'l', 'c', 'ooooo', 'm', 'eeeee']
```

Then we join them together with `"".join` to get `Weeeeelcooooomeeeee`

You can generalize the program a bit like this

```
def replace(word, count):
    return "".join([c * count if c in 'aeiouAEIOU' else c for c in word])

assert replace("Welcome", 2) == "Weelcoomee"
assert replace("Welcome", 3) == "Weeelcooomeee"
```

Answer (score 1):

using lists:

```
def replace(word):
    newword=[]
    for c in word:
        if c.lower() in 'aeiou':
            newword.append(c*5)
        else:
            newword.append(c)
    return ''.join(newword)
```

or with string replace

```
def vowelreplace(word):
    vowels='aeiouAEIOU'
    for c in vowels:
        word=word.replace(c, c*5)
    return word
```

easiest way with list comprehension:

```
def vowelreplace(word):
    return ''.join([i*5 if i in 'aeiouAEIOU' else i for i in word])
```